# simple expression evaluation for extended lightning component is sometimes wrong

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inheritance, expressions

In this simple and straightforward scenario the evaluation of an expression is not getting updated correctly.

I have two components, an (abstract) base component and an extended one:

cmBaseComponent:

```
<aura:component extensible="true" abstract="true">    

<aura:attribute name="selected" type="Boolean" />

<div>
    <lightning:input type="checkbox" name="selectedCB" label=" " checked="{!v.selected}" />
</div>

<div>
    Base component: {!v.selected} // {!v.selected ? 'true' : 'false'}
</div>

{!v.body}
```

cmExtendedComponent:

```
<aura:component extends="c:cmBaseComponent">    

<aura:set attribute="selected" value="true" />

Extended: {!v.selected} // {!v.selected ? 'true' : 'false'}
```

NOTE: I have no other logic - no controller or other bindings.

The result on the screen is this:

[image]

So far so good, means initial evaluation is correct.
BUT: when I toggle the checkbox the first time the result is:

[image]

Toggling again and again will always result in the right behavior - it just fails on the first data change.

Fiddling around finding out that:

- this only occurs when you set the attribute to true - `<aura:set attribute="selected" value="false" />` always renders correctly
- this only occurs in the extended class
- this only occurs when you use the expression in a tenary operator or other expression functions like `{! if(v.selected, 'true', 'false) }` - not when you use the expression `{!v.selected}` directly as in sample
- no difference toggling the value by using `ui:inputCheckbox` or `lightning:input`

Is this a bug in the framework or could anyone explain why this behavior is the way it is?

Comment: Long-shot: what if you put the concrete component's output in a <div> like the abstract component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed, bug in the framework.

I'll file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when u use aura:set , it should be for attribute values that can not be updated later ( maybe that during rerender of Base component, the aura:set is taken in account again )

I suggest you set your initial value in you extended component init handler so that there won't be problems once it's user updated.